# Integers Being Added to Array

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, docpad, eco

I'm trying to use an array of objects to simplify maintaining a list of HTML buttons. Here's my code:

```
<% links = [{url:"https://github.com/drguildo", icon:"github"}, %>
<% {url:"http://www.flickr.com/photos/drguildo/", icon:"flickr"}, %>
<% {url:"http://instagram.com/therac25", icon:"instagram"}, %>
<% {url:"http://www.last.fm/user/drguildo", icon:"lastfm"}] %>
<% for link in links: %>
<a href="<%= link.url %>"><img src="/img/icons/<%= link.icon %>.png" /></a>
<% end %>
```

The problem is the resulting array looks like this:

```
[object Object],16,[object Object],17,[object Object],18,[object Object]
```

which messes up the output. Why are the objects interspersed with integers and how can I prevent it?

I'm probably doing this in a very sub-optimal way (I'm new to DocPad, ECO and CoffeeScript) so any suggestions on how to improve my code would be appreciated.

Comment: Inserting Javascript arrays into scriplets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to be creating an array like this within the template.  The point of eco templates it to separate the logic/data from the presentation.  Declare the data separately, then use it to render the template.

Like this

```
eco = require "eco"
fs  = require "fs"

template = fs.readFileSync __dirname + "/views/test.html.eco", "utf-8"
console.log eco.render template, links: [
    {url:"https://github.com/drguildo", icon:"github"}, 
    {url:"http://www.flickr.com/photos/drguildo/", icon:"flickr"},
    {url:"http://instagram.com/therac25", icon:"instagram"},
    {url:"http://www.last.fm/user/drguildo", icon:"lastfm"}
]
```

and then just

```
<% for link in @links: %>
<a href="<%= link.url %>"><img src="/img/icons/<%= link.icon %>.png" /></a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I don't suppose you know how that would work with DocPad? For instance, where I would put that first bit of code.

Comment: looks like for docpad that would go into the config.coffee file, as a function that returns the array.  http://docpad.org/docs/begin#abstracting-logic-into-template-helpers